# Django Custom User Email Account Verification

Tags: django

I am looking to add email account verification in Django. I have attempted using the django-registration app to do so, but it doesn't appear that it has been updated to be fully compatible with custom user models which causes too many problems. Is there another reliable and well-documented app out there which will allow me to send a verification email on user registration in django?

Comment: How do you actually handle the registration of a new user? Is it a custom form? If so, you can override the save method to send your email (create the user as inactive, generate a link that you'll send in the email, when going to this link, activate the user)

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom UserCreationForm to create the user. So within that save method, after `user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)`, i should set `user.is_active = False` and then send an email with the confirmation code, and without any plug-in this can be done simply?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How I handle the email registration personally:

First of all, my Profile extending Django Users (`models.py`):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile') #1 to 1 link with Django User
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
```

In `forms.py`, the Registration class :

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nom d\'utilisateur','class':'form-control input-perso'}),max_length=30,min_length=3,validators=[isValidUsername, validators.validate_slug])
    email = forms.EmailField(label="",widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email','class':'form-control input-perso'}),max_length=100,error_messages={'invalid': ("Email invalide.")},validators=[isValidEmail])
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=50,min_length=6,
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mot de passe','class':'form-control input-perso'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=50,min_length=6,
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirmer mot de passe','class':'form-control input-perso'}))

    #recaptcha = ReCaptchaField()

    #Override clean method to check password match
    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            self._errors['password2'] = ErrorList([u"Le mot de passe ne correspond pas."])

        return self.cleaned_data

    #Override of save method for saving both User and Profile objects
    def save(self, datas):
        u = User.objects.create_user(datas['username'],
                                     datas['email'],
                                     datas['password1'])
        u.is_active = False
        u.save()
        profile=Profile()
        profile.user=u
        profile.activation_key=datas['activation_key']
        profile.key_expires=datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        profile.save()
        return u

    #Sending activation email ------>>>!! Warning : Domain name is hardcoded below !!<<<------
    #The email is written in a text file (it contains templatetags which are populated by the method below)
    def sendEmail(self, datas):
        link="http://yourdomain.com/activate/"+datas['activation_key']
        c=Context({'activation_link':link,'username':datas['username']})
        f = open(MEDIA_ROOT+datas['email_path'], 'r')
        t = Template(f.read())
        f.close()
        message=t.render(c)
        #print unicode(message).encode('utf8')
        send_mail(datas['email_subject'], message, 'yourdomain <no-reply@yourdomain.com>', [datas['email']], fail_silently=False)
```

Now, in `views.py`, we need to handle all that, let's go :

The register view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(home)
    registration_form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datas={}
            datas['username']=form.cleaned_data['username']
            datas['email']=form.cleaned_data['email']
            datas['password1']=form.cleaned_data['password1']

            #We generate a random activation key
            salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
            usernamesalt = datas['username']
            if isinstance(usernamesalt, unicode):
                usernamesalt = usernamesalt.encode('utf8')
            datas['activation_key']= hashlib.sha1(salt+usernamesalt).hexdigest()

            datas['email_path']="/ActivationEmail.txt"
            datas['email_subject']="Activation de votre compte yourdomain"

            form.sendEmail(datas)
            form.save(datas) #Save the user and his profile

            request.session['registered']=True #For display purposes
            return redirect(home)
        else:
            registration_form = form #Display form with error messages (incorrect fields, etc)
    return render(request, 'siteApp/register.html', locals())
```

The activation views :

```
#View called from activation email. Activate user if link didn't expire (48h default), or offer to
#send a second link if the first expired.
def activation(request, key):
    activation_expired = False
    already_active = False
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, activation_key=key)
    if profile.user.is_active == False:
        if timezone.now() > profile.key_expires:
            activation_expired = True #Display: offer the user to send a new activation link
            id_user = profile.user.id
        else: #Activation successful
            profile.user.is_active = True
            profile.user.save()

    #If user is already active, simply display error message
    else:
        already_active = True #Display : error message
    return render(request, 'siteApp/activation.html', locals())

def new_activation_link(request, user_id):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    datas={}
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    if user is not None and not user.is_active:
        datas['username']=user.username
        datas['email']=user.email
        datas['email_path']="/ResendEmail.txt"
        datas['email_subject']="Nouveau lien d'activation yourdomain"

        salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        usernamesalt = datas['username']
        if isinstance(usernamesalt, unicode):
            usernamesalt = usernamesalt.encode('utf8')
        datas['activation_key']= hashlib.sha1(salt+usernamesalt).hexdigest()

        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        profile.activation_key = datas['activation_key']
        profile.key_expires = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        profile.save()

        form.sendEmail(datas)
        request.session['new_link']=True #Display: new link sent

    return redirect(home)
```

Finally, in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^register/$', 'register'),
url(r'^activate/(?P<key>.+)$', 'activation'),
url(r'^new-activation-link/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'new_activation_link'),
```

With all that you should have something to start with, use the appropriate templatetags in the .txt emails and HTML and it should work.

NB: This code isn't perfect, there is duplication (for instance, the generation of the random key could be defined in a function), but it does the job. Also: the activation key is not generated using proper cryptographic functions. An alternative is to use a function like the following to generate the keys:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def generate_activation_key(username):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    secret_key = get_random_string(20, chars)
    return hashlib.sha256((secret_key + username).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

NB2: Django `send_mail` doesn't provide any tools to authenticate your emails. If you want to authenticate your emails (DKIM, SPF), I advise you to look into this: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1995/

NB3: There is a security issue with the view new_activation_link: it should check if the user requesting the re-send is the right one and also if he isn't already authenticated. I let you correct that.

Comment: @Raphael Laurent then , how should 'login' be done with token? The answer above is doing 'save()' not logging in

Comment: **Warning:** this answer does not use a secure way to generate the activation key, but instead relies only on the `random` module. A simple way to obtain a secure value is using `get_random_string` from `django.utils.crypto` (this is used to provide the default `SECRET_KEY` when using `startproject`) or, if using python3.6>, use the new `secrets` module. Otherwise use `os.urandom` to obtain real random data instead of `random.random`.

Comment: @raphael-laurent can I use uuid4() to generate a random key?

Comment: If you want to avoid hard-coding the activation link in your email, you can do `reg_data['activation_url'] = request.build_absolute_uri('/activate/')` in views.py. This answer was written in 2014/edited in 2017 but was still SUPER helpful for me to set up email confirmation! Thank you @Raphael and @Bakuriu.

Answer (score 4):

You may also be interested in the simple but powerful [django-verified-email-field](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-verified-email-field).

Simply use `VerifiedEmailField` in Your forms:

```
from django import forms
from verified_email_field.forms import VerifiedEmailField

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = VerifiedEmailField(label='email', required=True)
```

Or in Your models:

```
from django.db import models
from verified_email_field.models import VerifiedEmailField

class User(models.Model):
    email = VerifiedEmailField('e-mail')
```

It renders two input fields: `e-mail` and `verification code`. The verification code is sent to the e-mail address using AJAX or during field's `clean` if there is no valid code for given e-mail, so it works even without javascript.

Comment: Can you explain briefly..please

Comment: I've already explained it briefly. I'm not sure which part shall I explain more deeply, unles you ask some particular question.

Comment: this is a really poorly documented library

Comment: It's not a library, just a single (though powerful) model/form field.
(What documentation You expect when You buy a hammer? I suppose that the weight and the kind of wood is enough.)
You're welcome to extend the documentation, if You miss anything important. Or You may ask some reasonable question and I'll answer it and possibly update the README.